# How do I see how much memory every part of my activity takes up - imageview, sounds,animation?[android]

Tags: android, memory, android-studio

I have an activity that takes up 189mb, it is mostly media:sounds,imageViews, animation. in Android studio we have memory tab that shows **total** amount an activity occupies when onCreate.

How do i see it?

Comment: i think you can see how much your APP use NOT single activity

Comment: [http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/04/hunting-your-leaks-memory-management-in-android-part-2-of-2/](http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/04/hunting-your-leaks-memory-management-in-android-part-2-of-2/)

Answer (score 1):

I think installing new android studio you can use the tool that shows CPU usage and memory usage. But I'm not sure it give an information about activity or entire application...

Just try maybe that help.